# Why i have "error cannot find symbol" when importing some java files that are present in android source?

Tags: java, android

when i try to add

```
import android.view.WindowManagerGlobal;
```

then i receive the error :

```
error: cannot find symbol 
import android.view.WindowManagerGlobal;
                   ^
  symbol:   class WindowManagerGlobal
  location: package android.view
```

but i see in android source code that the file is present in **android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java**

why i can not import it? and as i absolutely need it, how can i import it ?

Comment: Because this class is not part of Android API

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to the classpath. One option is to download the related jar from [its github page](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base).

Can you tell us more about your environment?

Comment: thanks tamas, i compile a jar via the command line tool with javac (so this is my environment, plus notepad of course). so i just need to add the java file to my project and it's work ? i will not have any duplicate ?

Comment: I recommend to clone it, check out to the right release, build the jar, and add *that* to `javac` via -`cp`. It would be even better if you'd use an IDE like Android Studio to take care of the boilerplate for you.